# Enable javascript files caching

Tags: javascript, jsp, caching, struts-1

I have an index.jsp where I am including all the js files and then I am using the jsp:include to include the different jsps depending on struts action.
In the subsequent jsps also i am including some js files.

Whatevr js files I include in the index.jsp is getting cached, because there is no timestamp added to the js URL.
But the js files included in the subsequent jsps are not getting cached due to timestamp added to the js URL. 
My question is how to get rid of timestamp added to js url?

I am adding the js files in the jsp like in the following:

```
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

I am using Struts 1.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Who added the timestamp? Are you saying that struts is modifying your script tag, adding a query param to disable caching? Show the code that is calling calling `jsp:include` that contains the script tags above.

Comment: Maybe include all the js files on the top level rather than inside jsp files included in jsp includes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache:true});
});
```